# Several perl packages (including cpan and re.pl) not working after upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, perl, cpan

Several perl packages stopped working after upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04.

For example, `cpan` gives me:

```
Attempt to reload Scalar/Util.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/CPAN/Meta/Requirements.pm line 35.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/CPAN/Meta/Requirements.pm line 35.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl/5.18/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl/5.18/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl/5.18/CPAN.pm line 25.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl/5.18/CPAN.pm line 25.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl/5.18/App/Cpan.pm line 219.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl/5.18/App/Cpan.pm line 219.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/bin/cpan line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/cpan line 9.
```

and `re.pl` gives me:

```
Perl API version v5.14.0 of List::Util does not match v5.18.0 at /usr/share/perl/5.18/XSLoader.pm line 92.
Compilation failed in require at /home/abc/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/Scalar/Util.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2/Moose.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2/Moose.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Devel/REPL/Script.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Devel/REPL/Script.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/bin/re.pl line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/re.pl line 6.
```

Is there anyone to simply get a fresh install of `perl` and all of its packages?

Comment: there's a conflict between 5.14 and 5.18. I suspect that you have a local version of perl. Could you attach to your question the output of `type perl`? I think you probably just need to update your perl lib in `/usr/local/`. You probably also have a `PERLLIB` that includes incompatible modules from `/home/abc/perl5/lib`

Comment: Are you able to use Scalar::Util if you rename `/home/abc/perl5` to `/home/abc/perl5_old`?

Comment: @SylvainPineau `type perl` returns `perl is /usr/bin/perl`. Renaming `~/perl5` to `~/perl5_old` successfully allowed me to use `Scalar::Util` and run both `cpan` and `re.pl`! Should I go ahead and start installing `cpan` packages again, or is there something else that needs to be fixed so that the local `~/perl5` does what it's supposed to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in my comments above, there's a conflict between 5.14 and 5.18.

The proposed solution was renaming `~/perl5` to `~/perl5_old` so that both `cpan` and `re.pl` works again.

To answer your last question, I would manage `~/perl5` to run 5.18 using [`perlbrew`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/perlbrew).

See [How can I install a newer Perl without damaging the system install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005610/how-can-i-install-a-newer-perl-without-damaging-the-system-install)